# Sagemaker Python SDK endpoint name has extra datetime after creation

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When I create an inference endpoint with

```
model = sage.Model(ecr_image, role=role, name=algorithm_name)
model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type=instance_type)
```

the deployed endpoint's name has additional date time string attached, e.g.,`algorithm_name-2020-12-20...`. Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I can specify the endpoint name in deploy with:

```
model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type=instance_type, endpoint_name="custom name")
```